# VBA running really slow after replacing Select statements with "With" & "Do While"

Tags: excel, vba, loops, with-statement

So, I have some VBA code which basically inserts a few new columns into a dataset, putting a formula in each new column and dragging that down to the end of the dataset.

Before my changes, the code looked like this.

```
Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Size"
Range("A2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=('Data'!RC[3])+IF('Data'!RC[1]>0,'Data'!RC[1],""0"")"
Range("A2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:A" & LastRow)

Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "client"
Range("A2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[46],'[Client codes.xlsx]Sheet1'!C1:C2,2,0),""No"")"
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:A" & LastRow)
```

After reading a few articles about how using Select etc makes your code more buggy, I thought I would update my code using "with" statements and "do while" loops. However, one thing I have found is that now my code takes maybe 10x longer to run. As in, before it ran through all the set of column additions and formulas in about 2mins, and now I have had to interrupt the code twice after running for about 15mins.

My updated code is below:

```
Set r = Range("A:A")

With r
 .Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
End With

Set title = Range("A1")
Set cell = Range("A2")

With title
.FormulaR1C1 = "Size"
End With

With cell
Do While cell <= LastRow
    .FormulaR1C1 = "=('Data'!RC[3])+IF('Data'!RC[1]>0,'Data'!RC[1],""0"")"
    .AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:A" & LastRow)
    .Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop
End With

Set r = Nothing
Set title = Nothing
Set cell = Nothing

Set r = Range("A:A")

With r
 .Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
End With

Set title = Range("A1")
Set cell = Range("A2")

With title
.FormulaR1C1 = "client"
End With

With cell
Do While cell <= LastRow
    .FormulaR1C1 =  "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[46],'[Client codes.xlsx]Sheet1'!C1:C2,2,0),""No"")"
    .AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:A" & LastRow)
    .Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop
End With

Set r = Nothing
Set title = Nothing
Set cell = Nothing
```

I thought about removing the Autofill given i have a Do While loop, but then it only populates the second line in each column.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: If your code is working but slow then this is probably better presented in Code review.  Stackoverflow is for code that doesn't work, or doesn't work as expected.

Comment: You're not changing `cell`  i think should be `selection.row<= LastRow` avoid using select too.  As you know the start and end point you can just say `cell.resize(1,lastrow-cell.row).formula="A1*2"` for example

Answer (score 3):

You can significantly reduce the size of the code:

```
Sub test1()
    Dim colnames, formulae, i
    
    colnames = Array("Size", "Client")
    formulae = Array("=('Data'!RC[3])+IF('Data'!RC[1]>0,'Data'!RC[1],""0"")", _
               "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[46],'[Client codes.xlsx]Sheet1'!C1:C2,2,0),""No"")")
    
    With ActiveSheet 'it is better to specify the exact sheet
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 0 To UBound(colnames)
            .Columns("A").Insert CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromRightOrBelow
            .Range("A1") = colnames(i)
            .Range("A2").Resize(LastRow - 1).FormulaR1C1 = formulae(i)
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your loops never get exited. That is, the condition is `Do While cell <= lastrow`, but nowhere in the loops does the `cell` variable get changed at all. The process will come back to the start of the loop without finding anything different, so it will get stuck in the loop endlessly.

Looking at the loops, because you're using `Autofill` to populate the whole column, I don't think you need the loops at all.
Added to which, `with` is only really there to save typing the same variable over and over again, it's not really necessary for single-line actions.

So, try updating your code to;

```
Set r = Range("A:A")

r.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove


Set title = Range("A1")
Set cell = Range("A2")

title.FormulaR1C1 = "Size"

With cell
    .FormulaR1C1 = "=('Data'!RC[3])+IF('Data'!RC[1]>0,'Data'!RC[1],""0"")"
    .AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:A" & LastRow)
End With

Set r = Range("A:A")

r.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

Set title = Range("A1")
Set cell = Range("A2")
title.FormulaR1C1 = "client"

With cell
    .FormulaR1C1 =  "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[46],'[Client codes.xlsx]Sheet1'!C1:C2,2,0),""No"")"
    .AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:A" & LastRow)
End With

Set r = Nothing
Set title = Nothing
Set cell = Nothing
```

Comment: Note that you don't need `AutoFill` either: `Range("A2:A" & LastRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=('Data'!RC[3])+IF('Data'!RC[1]>0,'Data'!RC[1],""0"")"`